# Creating wordpress admin page template in your theme

Tags: wordpress

Im making wordpress theme and I want to make custom page templates in wordpress admin backend. I already made admin menu in functions.php , but where should I add files or do I need to define them to use in wp-admin?

P.S. I dont want to make plugin for that, I want that only my theme would support this so this should be in theme folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the Wordpress Codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Particularly this part:

```
    <?php
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}

/** Step 3. */
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Although this is plugins: It's a very similar part. You would place the theme part inside your functions.php and use the appropriate hooks found on the codex to implement the extra pages.

```
 <?php
add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
?>
```

Comment: Ok, what about not writing all that html in functions.php? Should I use php include function to include custom template or this is inappropriate way to do?

Comment: You would probably be best to use the PHP hook to Create the pages in the menu etc, such as function my_plugin_menu and add_action. But then include each different page separately which uses the parts with HTML. That way you keep neat practice